# Apache Airflow with Python Exception: Expected state: SUCCESS. Actual state: failed

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I'm running apache-airflow on my Mac m1 to insert data from a staging table(the temporary table was created from S3) to AWS redshift.
The following error was raised, and it doesn't tell me what the source issue is. Could anybody please help me debug?

```
[2022-07-30 16:16:58,226] {subdag.py:186} INFO - Execution finished. State is failed
[2022-07-30 16:16:58,252] {taskinstance.py:1909} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1471, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context, test_mode)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1621, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    self.task.post_execute(context=context, result=result)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/subdag.py", line 189, in post_execute
    raise AirflowException(f"Expected state: SUCCESS. Actual state: {dag_run.state}")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Expected state: SUCCESS. Actual state: failed
[2022-07-30 16:16:58,268] {taskinstance.py:1415} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=sparkify_dag, task_id=load_artist_dim_table, execution_date=20220729T174100, start_date=20220730T161557, end_date=20220730T161658
[2022-07-30 16:16:58,298] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 399 for task load_artist_dim_table (Expected state: SUCCESS. Actual state: failed; 55013)
[2022-07-30 16:16:58,356] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-07-30 16:16:58,426] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: SubDAGs are deprecated. Don't use it. Your issue is most likely to be solved by just moving to TaskGroup.